# Read Contents of a Sharepoint Multiline Textbox in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am reading the contents of a list into a number of string variables so as to be able to build the content an HTML email.

The method I am using (and works for single line text boxes) is:

```
string Manager = item["Manager"].ToString();
```

However, when I try the same method for a multi-line text box I get the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can someone advise the best way in which to get the content of a multi-line text box into a variable that I can then reference for the other functionality mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that your item["Manager"] indexer does not find a column by that type. When it then tries to call .ToString() on it (null) it will result in the exception you are seeing.

Make sure you have the correct name (**internal name, not display name!**) for your notes column.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps your instance of SPListItem the item variable is null.

When you try to get a OOB SharePoint Field it's best practice to use the SPBuiltInFieldId class or the ID of the Field instead of the internal name.

```
item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title]
```